# Google Sheets - Duplicate Master tabs daily, rename by date and hide previous duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a spreadsheet with 3 tabs - Master X, Master Y and Master Z.

I'd like these tabs to automatically duplicate at midnight, and be renamed with the date they're copied in the following format - Master X 23/07.

Preferably these master tabs would be hidden, and then old tabs duplicated the previous date would automatically be hidden - so on any given day, there would only be today's 3 tabs visible.

The process is the following:

1. calculate the date of today and yesterday according to the format: DD/MM,
2. Find the master sheets and duplicate them
3. rename the newly created sheets with the today date,
4. hide the yesterday sheets,
5. create a daily trigger to make this process automated.

Would anyone be able to support with a script which actions all of the above please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step you need to do is to add the following code snippet to a new script:

```
 function MasterXYZ() {
  
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 const patternX = 'Master X';
 const patternY = 'Master Y';
 const patternZ = 'Master Z';
 
 var masterX = source.getSheetByName(patternX);
 var masterY = source.getSheetByName(patternY);
 var masterZ = source.getSheetByName(patternZ);

 masterX.copyTo(source).setName(patternX+" " + getDates()[1]).showSheet();
 masterY.copyTo(source).setName(patternY+ " " + getDates()[1]).showSheet();
 masterZ.copyTo(source).setName(patternZ+ " " + getDates()[1]).showSheet();
  
 masterX.hideSheet();
 masterY.hideSheet();
 masterZ.hideSheet();
 
  try{
 source.getSheetByName(patternX+" " + getDates()[0]).hideSheet();
 source.getSheetByName(patternY+ " " + getDates()[0]).hideSheet();
 source.getSheetByName(patternZ+ " " + getDates()[0]).hideSheet();  
  }
  catch(e){Logger.log("There are no yesterday's sheets")}
 
}

function getDates() {
 
  var today = new Date();
  
  var yesterday = new Date()
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1)
   
  var today_month = addZero(today.getMonth()+1)
  var today_day = addZero(today.getDate())
  
  var yesterday_month = addZero(yesterday.getMonth()+1)
  var yesterday_day = addZero(yesterday.getDate())
 
  var today_date =  today_day.toString() + "/" + today_month.toString()
  var yesterday_date =  yesterday_day.toString() + "/" + yesterday_month.toString()
  
  return [yesterday_date,today_date]


}

function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Then you need to setup a daily trigger for the MasterXYZ() by clicking on the current project's trigger menu and then add new trigger.

You only need to execute the function: MasterXYZ(). The rest are helper functions.

Comment: Nearly there - the newly created sheets with today's date are now being hidden, when they shouldn't be!

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. We are only hiding yesterday's sheets ( if there are any, that explains the addition of the try error function in the script. Could you please delete all the sheets and keep only the master X,y,z and run the script again ?

Comment: So, with a fresh sheet with just Master X, Y and Z tabs, it is correctly duplicating and renaming and hiding the old versions. However, I've tried renaming what it has duplicated to yesterday's date to see if it would recognise yesterday's sheets. It hides these and creates new sheets, but the new sheets do not reappear. Sorry if I'm being difficult!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help and understanding - massively appreciated :)

Comment: Hope you can help - I have amended this script to duplicate on Master X - how do I go about making this the active sheet and moving this to first position (the first sheet in the workbook?).

Comment: Apologies. Upvoted and have asked as a new question. Thank you